# How to handle defaulted optional fields in an options parameter for a TypeScript class whilst letting user chose provided arguments?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, option-type, nullable

I'm trying to determine how to handle optional fields in an options argument for a TypeScript class whilst only requiring the user of the class to provide only the arguments they need so all other options are defaulted (use case is allowing the user to customize the class via the options)

For example, if there's a class (e.g., `Logger`) that accepts an options argument (e.g., `IOptions`) where all options are optional & will be defaulted in the constructor. Then all `IOptions` fields can be nullable so the user only provides the arguments they need (e.g., customizing the `Logger`). This is fine since all nullable values will be defaulted in the constructor, however, if the options argument is used throughout the class, the compiler will error since the fields are marked as nullable in `IOptions`. However, the constructor has defaulted all options so they should be safe but to avoid the error, either repeated null assertions are used (e.g., `this.options.logTag!!`) or the defaulting is repeated (e.g., `this.options.logTag ?? 'NONE`), both of these attempts to avoid errors are not ideal

Please explain how a defaulted options object can be used whilst only requiring the user to provide the fields they need?

Please also share any resources that might be helpful in answering this questin.

Example `Logger` class:

```js
interface IOptions {
    logTag?: string;
    // ...
}

class Logger {
    private options: IOptions; // Assume options are always contained & accessed from this object.

    constructor(options: IOptions = {}) {
        this.options = {
            ...options,
            logTag: options.logTag ?? 'NONE',
            // ...
        }
    }

    private saveTag(tag: string, message: string) { // Example demonstrating requiring non-null option value (logTag could be used directly, but passed here for example).
        // ... (e.g., formatting, saving, etc.)
    }

    log(message: string) {
        this.saveTag(this.options.logTag); // ERROR: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

        // ...
    }

}

const logger = new Logger();
logger.log('message');
```

Comment: Why is `logTag` optional in `IOptions`? If you make it required, then the constructor parameter becomes `options: Partial<IOptions> = {}` and everything else works: https://tsplay.dev/WkGJlW.

Comment: Good point, `logTag` was optional so the user didn't need to provide it but this pattern of letting the user select options they want to change seems like it might repeat in other customizable classes available to users so `Logger` was used as an example but if there was another class where the option needed to be optional, is there a pattern to have optional options? `Partial` looks like it might work here as the fields could all be required in the class but left partial to the user

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found `Required` solves the problem in this case for `Logger`, I'll post this as an answer but I'd like to find out if anyone know of better ways for handling optional options objects

Comment: That's just the same thing the other way, either you generate the "inside" type from the "outside" type with Required (https://tsplay.dev/WvE9Qm), or the "outside" type from the "inside" type with Partial. It's helpful to be familiar with the [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) in general.

Comment: Yes, `Required` is generated from the outside type & the other way could be having the argument as `Partial`, actually, `Partial` seems cleaner (please post an answer & I can accept to help others). Do you know if there's a preference or convention between the two? Also, good advice on utility types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @jonrsharpe's suggestion of `Partial`, I found `Required` solves the problem by letting the user provide any of the optional fields whilst avoiding the errors of potentially null options without using repeated null assertions or repeated defaulting:

```js
private options: Required<IChangeloggerOptions>;
```

This means IChangeloggerOptions has fields that all remain nullable whilst the options in the class will all be required (these options won't error as they're all defaulted in the constructor)